# How can I improve my simple mysql query speed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple query that keeps cropping up in my slow query log.  When it crops up it typically says the query took about 3-6 seconds.  Here is the query:

```
UPDATE company_users 
SET isonline=1, last_logon='2011-12-05 19:37:11', last_message=-1, 
    last_signal=-1, location=-1 
WHERE userid='3546600442XXXXX';
```

I have to use the userid comparison as that is the information I have at the time of the update.

The database structure is:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id      int(11) NO  PRI \N  auto_increment
userid  varchar(20) NO  MUL     
version varchar(3)  YES     37  
owneruserid int(11) NO  MUL 0   
simcard_phonenumber varchar(20) YES     \N  
registration_date   date    YES     \N  
labelname   varchar(20) YES     \N  
isonline    smallint(6) YES     0   
last_logon  datetime    YES     \N  
last_message    int(11) YES     0   
last_voltage    int(11) YES     0   
last_reboot datetime    YES     \N      
connect_mode    int(11) YES     1   
scheduleid  int(11) YES MUL -1  
location        int(11) YES MUL -1  
img             varchar(50) YES
```

I have indexes of the following:

company_users   0   PRIMARY 1   id  A   197 \N  \N      BTREE
company_users   1   indx_userid 1   userid  A   197 \N  \N      BTREE
company_users   1   indx_location   1   location    A   12  \N  \N  YES BTREE
company_users   1   indx_scheduleid 1   scheduleid  A   49  \N  \N  YES BTREE
company_users   1   indx_owneruserid    1   owneruserid A   197 \N  \N      BTREE

The table has about 300 rows in it.  The database is on the same server as my website.  These queries are run using a PHP script.

Hopefully that is enough info to get some idea of what I might be doing wrong, or where I can tweak my config.

UPDATE:
After the suggestion by Dennis I had another look at my slow query log and noticed there were three statements logged against a time frame.  This was the info for two of them which were the same type of update statement identified above:

**Query_time: 5  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0**

**Query_time: 5  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0**

**Query_time: 4  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1**

This last was for a select on the same table.  I did an analyze on the select statement (as I didn't know how to do that on an Update) and it showed:

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra1  SIMPLE  company_users   const   indx_imei   indx_imei   22  const   1

Comment: For a table with 300 rows the query should fly even without any indexes. But an index on `user_id` might be useful in future (you already have it).

Answer (score 2):

Having a lot of indexes can speed up select statements, but slow down inserts, updates, and deletes. My first suggestion would be to remove the indexes and re-execute the queries to see if time is improved.

Comment: The indexes are there to help with joins I use on this table with other tables.  Have I got this wrong?  The indexes I use in this situation is the location, scheduleid and owneruserid ones

Comment: No you are correct, indexes do help improve speed when joining tables; however I would limit the number of indexes to the bare minimum if you plan to do a lot of updating/inserting/deleting of rows. Also if you could include the explain plan in your question I believe that would help a lot. More details can be found here in case you are not familiar with EXPLAIN, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the problem issue, updating a record on a flat table of 300 records, is not related to the indexes.  It sounds like your insert statement is being blocked by another statement .  Is it always slow or slow only under certain conditions, this would further make it seem that blocking is the likely candidate.  You need more information really.  I would investigate possible blocking selects on that table to see if they are a culprit, and see initially if those queries can be optimised before looking at things like the transaction isolation levels and autocommit config.

If the problem is a select query locking you could verify (and possibly solve your issue) by running the select query without locking.  This could be done by

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ; -- Place your select query here
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ ;
```

However, this approach has some health warnings associated with it.  It is a better practice to get more info about what is wrong and solve the offending queries by making them as close as optimal as possible rather than using this approach.

I remember this [Coding Horror blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html) as having some useful insights.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It does possibly seem like something like that.  However wouldn't those show up in the slow query log as well?  Are there any techniques or things I can do in order to identify any blocking selects as this sounds like a possible culprit

Answer (score 1):

I agree with AlexC that most likely another statement is blocking your UPDATE statement. If you want to make certain your UPDATES are not getting blocked, you could work with two databases. On the master db you do your UPDATES and INSERTS and the second, which is replicated from the first, is where all the SELECTing is happening.

Alternatively, you could certainly figure out what statements are actually blocking your query and try optimizing them. On a heavily selected database this might not be easily achievable.

Comment: Thanks Sascha.  Not sure if two databases is a plan at the moment however it might be something we need to look into in the future perhaps

Comment: Not sure how your production environment looks like, but a possible way to test weather other queries block the update would be to make sure no other query is run while performing an update (ofc :). If the database is not live I'd just try and make sure the UPDATE query is the only one that is executed and weather it is still as slow.